# The resource file en-US not rendered properly

Tags: silverlight-5.0, globalization, app-globalresources

I have a silverlight application supports English, Japanese and French.

I could change Japanese to French and French to Japanese and i tried to load French to English and Japanese to English it loads Japanese only.

This issue exist only in Windows 7 JPN environment. Why? how to overcome this issue?

Note: browser language is ja-JP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a very simple soln for this,

Please include the Language code in **cs.proj** file that will fix this.